# Shouldn't a Redux app with immutable data run out of memory after a while?

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I come from a background in embedded systems where you're really careful about memory management. With Redux especially its concept of immutability.
So let's say I'm modifying a member of an array. I have to create a new array that links to all original members plus the modified item.

I understand why using Immutability improves the speed but my question is since we essentially never remove the old copies of the objects and create new ones, Redux still keeps a reference to the old objects because of time traveling features.

Most machines these days have quite a lot of memory, but shouldn't at least in theory the Redux app crash because the tab/process runs out of memory? After a long use maybe?

Comment: You can measure this yourself, if using a browser such as Chrome that provides tab-by-tab memory usage. Keep in mind that it's only *usage* that creates new states that's pertinent -- if a tab is sitting idle in one state, it's... well, idle.

Comment: ...short form: Yes, memory grows over time, but if you're expecting to be t*n (where t is the number of states passed through and n is the average size of storage for a single state), that worst-case is very unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  First, Redux itself doesn't keep around old data - that's something that the Redux DevTools addon does.  Second, I believe the DevTools addon has limits on how many actions it will track.  Third, Javascript is a garbage-collected language, so items that are no longer referenced will be cleaned up.  (Hand-waving a bit there, but that generally covers things.)

Comment: You seem to beavoiding touching upon half of the subject: immutable data structures. Redux does not have immutable data structures, and will by default assume you are operating on data _as if they were_ immutable _by convention_. The OP does not assume this: he is explicitly talking about using immutable data structures, such as Immutable.js and Ramda, in conjunction with Redux. In that case, one _might_ run out of data at some point, as you hold _all versions in memory_, but it is entirely dependent on how you "modify" the structures, as the other answer points to.

Comment: Uh... no.  The OP refers to "immutability", but does not mention Immutable.js or Ramda.  Also, even if using Immutable.js, standard JS garbage collection rules still apply. If you no longer have a reference to a particular Immutable.js object, and no other Immutable objects refer to the older structurally shared nodes, they will be GC'd.  See https://medium.com/@dtinth/immutable-js-persistent-data-structures-and-structural-sharing-6d163fbd73d2 for discussion. Also see my post at http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/ for info on Redux + immutability.

Answer (score 3):

Immutable.js leverages the idea of Structural Sharing while creating new copies of collections. It implements persistent data structures and internally uses concepts like [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to implement structural sharing. So, if you created a list with 10 items, adding a new item to it will not create a new list.

> Persistent data structures provide the benefits of immutability while
>   maintaining high performance reads and writes and present a familiar
>   API.
>   Immutable.js data structures are highly efficient on modern JavaScript VMs by
>   using structural sharing via hash maps tries and vector tries as
>   popularized by Clojure and Scala, minimizing the need to copy or cache
>   data.

I suggest you watch this [awesome talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7IdS-PbEgI) by Lee Bryon, Immutable.js creator

Comment: That is true, but you might very well run out of memory if your usage patterns are special. If you have a list of ten numbers, and you modify the list by incrementing every number, you then have 20 numbers in memory - plus the associated structures around it. Do it again, and you have 30 numbers, etc.